# Microsoft SQL: abstract script for multiple databases

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I need to replicate image catalog records from one server to another who's database names start with `p_` I can hard code it like so (one out of many statements):

```
delete
from      p_PhotoDB.dbo.item_keyword
where     not exists (
    select  null as nothing
    from    OtherServer.p_PhotoDB.dbo.item_keyword new
    where   p_PhotoDB.dbo.item_keyword.item_id = new.item_id and
            p_PhotoDB.dbo.item_keyword.keyword_id = new.keyword_id
)
```

I know I could put the entire thing in a string variable and `exec (@variable)`, but this would compile each time for each statement for each catalog ...

Is there a way to change the `p_PhotoDB` reference for each found database starting with `p_` without using some form of `exec (@variable)`?

Comment: What do you mean by "compile"? Have you tested using dynamic SQL for this? Was there a performance (or other) problem that you specifically saw, or are you just assuming that there will be?

Comment: I wrote it with exec( @variable) which includes user input, so potential for injection, but it does take about a minute to run, even if it has nothing to do.  Just wondering if there's a nice trick or something that I could do to reference a set of database names in these queries.

Answer (score 1):

Dr Zim.,

To the best of my knowledge, that can't be done at the database level.

There are, of course, tools that can help you do this such as Redgate Compare, or built into various versions of Visual Studio.

If you need a way to automate this in a periodically running script, you might be able to use SYNONYMS for tables, but there is definitely some up front work required there, and it is definitely not useful in a number of situations. SEE: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `exec(@variable)`, use `exec sp_ExecuteSQL`. It creates one execution plan as opposed to a new one for each execution. See [MSDN's Using sp_ExecuteSQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) article. You can then use dynamic SQL to change the dbname or use a loop to loop through a set of databases. In semi-pseudocode:

```
Set @DbList='p_db1,p_db2,p_db3,...'

--- Loop through comma separated list and build dynamic sql
-- while
set @SQL='delete
from      '+@CurrentDBName+'.dbo.item_keyword
where     not exists (
    select  null as nothing
    from    OtherServer.p_PhotoDB.dbo.item_keyword new
    where   '+@CurrentDBName+'.dbo.item_keyword.item_id = new.item_id and
            '+@CurrentDBName+'.dbo.item_keyword.keyword_id = new.keyword_id
)'

-- end while
exec sp_ExecuteSQL @SQL,N''
```